# Blender Output Multiple Passes When Rendering with Specific Naming Scheme (2.8.2a)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, render-layers, render-passes

My render setup looks like this:

[image]

and my file output looks like this (the mist pass is put in that folder with the names "Image0000.png" and "Image0001.png"):

[image]

but my desired output is this:

[image]

how can I get my desired render output in Blender? I'm using Blender 2.8.2a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your image it looks like you are assigning a folder called "Mist". select a folder and then use the add input inside the File output node <kbd>N</kbd> and connect your "mist" to that new input

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!